How to create Search TextField with height 30?
This is my search Field the problem which i am facing is with the specific height if i reduce the height of the TextField then the text inside is not visible but with normal height it's visible.
   Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(30.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = query,
            onValueChange = {
                query = it
                if (query.isNotEmpty())
                    active = true
            },
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(top = 10.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
            placeholder = { Text(placeholder) },
            singleLine = true,
            textStyle = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 8.sp,
                color = Color.Black
            ),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                containerColor = lightGray,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent, // Hide the indicator line when focused
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent // Hide the indicator line when unfocused
            ),
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_search), // Use your search icon resource
                    contentDescription = "Search",
                    tint = Color.Gray // Optional: Change the icon color
                )
            },
            trailingIcon = {
                if (active) {
                    Icon(
                        tint = Color.Gray,
                        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                            if (query.isNotEmpty()) {
                                query = ""
                                onClear()
                            } else {
                                active = false
                            }
                        },
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Close,
                        contentDescription = "Close icon"
                    )
                }
            },
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onSearch = {
                if (query.isNotEmpty())
                    onSearch(query)

            }, onDone = {
                if (query.isNotEmpty()) {
                    active = true
                    onSearch(query)
                }
            }),
            )
    }

but when i try to enter something is not visible with less height.
I need TextField with 30.dp height with leading and trailing icon as shown in provided code.

Your problem is the inner padding of the TextField. See the question remove default padding on jetpack compose textfield for how it can be removed.
